# Open in new tab (not new window) using any method possible

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tabs

I know that there are lots of duplicate questions like mine but I couldn't find any solution. I'm having trouble with opening a new tab in my code. I want to open a new tab - *not a window* - without any click on any button, and I need it to run automatically.

This is my code but it open's a new window instead of a new tap.

code:

```
if (isset($_POST['check'])){
  ?><script>window.open('reports/education_efficacy.php','_blank');</script><?php
}
```

meta refresh version: 
(it redirects to the target page in the same page, and I wonder is there any way to redirect to a new tab?)

```
if (isset($_POST['check'])){
  echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; URL=javascript:window.open('reports/relation_with_health.php\','_new');\">";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: As i said there are duplicate questions like mine but there is no solution for my problem , so please do not close my post.

Comment: There is no solution that will work in all cases, and attempting to restrict how a user uses there browser isn't a good idea

Comment: @MarkBaker I just need one solution for this matter , I need to open a new tab without any button clicking or etc just if the condition is true open a new tab .

Comment: is there any way to auto submit a form via jquery or javascript and open a windows in new tab ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the bel open a new tap and stay in current tap (crtl+click) function like.

java code :

```
<script>
        document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", openNewBackgroundTab, false);

        function openNewBackgroundTab(url){
            var a = document.createElement("a");
             a.href = url;
            var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");    
            evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
            a.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
    </script>
```

html code :

```
<a href="#" id="test" onclick="openNewBackgroundTab('reports/education_efficacy.php')" >education efficacy</a>
```

Comment: Thanks in advance, Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
window.open('reports/relation_with_health.php\','_blank')
```

Comment: is there any way to auto submit a form via jquery or javascript and open a windows in new tab ?

Comment: There is a way to auto submit form using jquery. you can use $('#yourformId').submit(); to submit a form using jquery.